# Acumatica REST API - Response body is empty when receiving successfully 200 calls. This only occurs intermittently

Tags: acumatica

Once in a while, my API calls to Acumatica will not return a response body, but still return a 200. The same call will be successful after a few minutes.

My guess is that I might be hitting limitations on the number of API requests per minute, or concurrent requests. It's hard to know when the requests are coming back as 200. There are no response headers that indicate an error.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: What type of transaction are you trying to run?  Is it a long running process like releasing a document?

Comment: I was trying to run quick GET requests to retrieve inventory non-stock items. My guess is that Acumatica is swallowing API limit exceptions, and returning back empty "successful" requests.

Comment: Typically you get an error code of 429 when you hit a login limit.
Reference: https://twitter.com/TimRodman/status/1204503535074852864
https://www.acumatica.com/media/2020/09/AcumaticaERP_IntegrationDevelopmentGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track regarding reaching a limit.   I have experienced delayed requested but not declined requests from the API.  There is definitely a limit based on the license on the Acumatica site.  You should be able to take a look at the License Monitoring Console screen in Acumatica to see if there are any API violations -- Number of transactions per minute, delayed transactions and declined transactions are all logged and shown in the statistics on this page.

The image below shows an example of this page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this screen confirmed that I had limits being reached. Still a bit strange that I'm receiving empty 200 responses as a "Declined" request, but I was able to tweak my logic to prevent the app from reaching API limits.

Comment: Glad to hear this helped!